# Excel - Use the result from VLOOKUP in another VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

So, i basicaly have this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;Imena!$A$1:$C$208;2;)&" "&VLOOKUP(A2;Imena!$A$1:$C$208;3;)
```

It combines First and Last name of a user from Sheet "Imena" based on a A2 value

Now, i would like to do anouther Vlookup like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(__result of first vlookup__;Sheet2!$N$2:$O$940;1;FALSE)
```

Based on the result of first lookup, do another... How can that be done? I tried formating the cells, nothing... Adding -- in front of VLOOKUP (read that online), didnt help...

Maybe someone of you knows the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the below didnt work, i ended up creating a temp sheet with only values of the first VLOOKUP, then using the data in another VLOOKUP. maybe its my Excel, i dont know... Thanks all anyways...

Answer (score 4):

Although it doesn't really answer OPs question, I came across this thread while looking for a similar answer. I have a formula that returns a number, then I do a vLookup of that number, expect it doesn't work. What I figured out was that you need to put value() around your lookup_value, like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(J9),Sheet7!$A$1:$C$563,3,FALSE)
```

The issue is that the value in J9 was text, instead of a number.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, whether or not it answered OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=VLOOKUP((VLOOKUP(A2,'Imena'!$A$1:$C$208,2,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(A2,'Imena'!$A$1:$C$208,3,FALSE)),'Sheet2'!$N$2:$O$940,1,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If e.g. cell `A1` holds your first formula, then just insert a reference to `A1` in your second formula.
Alternatively, just insert your first formula in its entirety (except for the equal sign) in your second formula.

Note that in your second formula your *range_lookup* is `FALSE`, so your *table_array* `Sheet2!$N$2:$O$940` does not need to be sorted.
Using `FALSE` here also means that `VLOOKUP` will find an *exact match*. If one is not found, the *error value* `#N/A` is returned.
—> So please mind e.g. any whitespace differences (trailing spaces) between your lookup value vs. the values in your lookup array…